# Placement coordinates of bitmapData in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

i've programatically created a vector graphic (rect), repositioned the graphic, and set up an MOUSE_MOVE eventListener to trace color information of the graphic using getPixel().  however, the bitmapData is placed at 0,0 of the stage and i don't know how to move it so that it matches the graphic's location.

```
var coloredSquare:Sprite = new GradientRect(200, 200, 0xFFFFFF, 0x000000, 0xFF0000, 0xFFFF00);
coloredSquare.x = 100;

addChild(coloredSquare);

var coloredSquareBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(coloredSquare.width, coloredSquare.height, true, 0);
coloredSquareBitmap.draw(coloredSquare);

coloredSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, readColor);
function readColor(evt:Event):void
    {
    var pixelValue:uint = coloredSquare.getPixel(mouseX, mouseY);
    trace(pixelValue.toString(16));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the square's transformation matrix (which contains the translation as well) as the second parameter of the [`draw()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) method

e.g.

```
coloredSquareBitmap.draw(coloredSquare,coloredSquare.transform.matrix);
```

Comment: hi george.  i had tried that but the mouse event is lost on the right half of the coloredSquare.  it seems to work only for the left half.

Comment: +1. although `concatenatedMatrix` is better, since it works in all cases, an not just if the parent has no transformation applied.

Comment: oh i see my mistake now. you did actually answer the question but my mouse event was causing errors. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var pixelValue:uint = coloredSquare.getPixel(coloredSquare.mouseX, coloredSquare.mouseY);
```

That way the mouseX / mouseY will be local to the coloured square and thus the bitmap duplicate .

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully understand the problem or the code. Maybe this helps:

```
coloredSquareBitmap.draw(coloredSquare, coloredSquare.transform.concatenatedMatrix);
```